# c++ Operator functions

Tags: c++, function, operator-keyword

im trying to Set the name of A to "new name" and return the reference of A
however im getting an error from the operator= function  `binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [6]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

```
expression must be a modifiable value.
```

If i simply do `return n = "new name";` it returns a segmentation fault

Please pay attention to my operator= function in my Account.cpp file.

Here are my three files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace sict;
using namespace std;

    int main(){
      Account A;
      Account B("Saving", 10000.99);
      Account C("Checking", 100.99);
      double value = 0;
      cout << A << endl << B << endl << C << endl << "--------" << endl;
      A = B + C;
      A = "Joint";
      cout << A << endl << B << endl << C << endl << "--------" << endl;
      A = B += C;
      cout << A << endl << B << endl << C << endl << "--------" << endl;
      value += A;
      value += B;
      value += C;
      cout << "Total balance: " << value << endl;
      return 0;
    }
```

Here is my Account.cpp i removed functions that i thought were unnecessary.
Edit: I'll include my entire account.cpp and account.h

Account.cpp:

```
  #include "cstring"
#include "iomanip"
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;
namespace sict{
  Account::Account(){
    _name[0] = 0;
    _balance = 0;
  }
  Account::Account(double balance){
    _name[0] = 0;
    _balance = balance;
  }

  Account::Account(const char name[], double balance){
    strncpy(_name, name, 40);
    _name[40] = 0;
    _balance = balance;
  }
  void Account::display()const{
    cout << _name << ": $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << _balance;
  }
  Account& Account::operator+=(Account &s1)  {
     // return Account(_balance += s1._balance);
      _balance += s1._balance;
      return *this;

  }

  Account& Account::operator=( Account& n) const {
```

strncpy(n._name , n, 40);

```
      return n;
  }
  double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a){
      d += a;
      return d;
  }
  ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Account& A){
    A.display();
    return os;
}
  Account operator+(const Account &p1, const Account &p2){
    return Account(p1._balance + p2._balance);
  }



}
```

Here is the Declaration for the Operator= in Account.h

```
#ifndef SICT_ACCOUNT_H__
#define SICT_ACCOUNT_H__
#include <iostream>
namespace sict{
  class Account{
    char _name[41];
    double _balance;
  public:
    Account();
    Account(const char name[], double balance = 0.0);
    Account(double balance);
    void display()const;
     friend Account operator+(const Account &p1, const Account &p2);
     Account& operator+=(Account& s1)   ;
    Account& operator=( Account& n) const;


  };
  Account operator+(const Account &p1, const Account &p2);
  double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a);
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& C);
};

#endif
```

Any help/tips would be appreciated thanks.

Edit: Added some code to operator=

Comment: What error did you encounter?

Comment: @cad, I listed the error above.

Comment: Why don't you just use `strncpy` again, like you did before?

Comment: Can you copy literal text into strncpy? such as strncpy(n._name , "new name", 40); ?

Comment: In your edit, you have switched the first two operands of the strncpy function.  Did you look up the reference to strncpy that I referenced below?

Comment: @AnonMail, yes i wanna put "new name" or "joint" into n._name.. not sure how to do that

Comment: That's not how an assignment operator works.  The signature operator= has a well defined meaning in C++.  If you want your class to do something that is not assignment, then name your function something else.  Otherwise you confuse everybody.

Comment: i specifically want to set  _name into whatever string is passed into n,

Comment: I renamed you Account::operator= to Account::foo.  And it compiled and ran successfully.

Comment: Use `std::string` please.

Answer (score 2):

You `operator=` is written backwards!

```
Account& Account::operator=( Account& n) const {
    strncpy(n._name , n, 40);
    return n;
}
```

It should be:

```
Account& Account::operator=(const Account& n){
    strncpy(_name, n._name, 40);
    return *this;
}
```

When you write `A = B;` then it is like `A.operator=(B)`. So `A` will be `*this` (the object assigned to) and `B` will be `n` (the original one).

But you have a small issue with the actual use. Since there is no `operator=` that takes a string as argument, your code:

```
A = "new name";
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
A = Account("new name");
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
A = Account("new name", 0.0);
```

No harm done because `operator=` does not assign to the balance, only to the name. But you probably should not be doing this...

My advice, do not overload operator just for fun: use normal member functions.

PS: Issues with `strncpy` apart, I'm not entering in those.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an array.  In your case, you can do a strncpy (as you did in your constructor) into the array.  But, in general, it's much better to use std::string.

Comment: `strncpy(n._name, _name); ` ?

Comment: No.  You would have to supply an n as the third argument.  Also, look up std::strncpy so you know the arguments it expects.  See that here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy

Comment: std::strncpy(_name,n._name, 40); Wont work. Says error under _name 
const char is incompatible with char

Comment: All i need it to do is set the name passed reference or for example A to new name
so shouldnt n._name = "new name"; work?

Comment: With some minor adjustments I was able to get it to compile strncpy to work by doing the same thing as in your constructor.  The adjustments were to remove the const qualifier from the assignment operator member function.  And to make the argument to the assignment operator const.

Comment: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [6]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Can you edit you code in the original question so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Could i possible use string& operator=( const string& str);?
i tried using it however it wouldnt let me implement it.

Comment: **Don't use `strncpy`**, unless you really have to deal in 0-padded (*not* terminated) buffers of fixed length.

Comment: What would i do then? I'm lost haha

Comment: @deduplicator what do you mean?

Comment: Make `_name` a `std::string`. Or at least be consistent in whether it's a C-string stored in the beginning of that buffer, or non-zero bytes stored in a zero-padded buffer of fixed length.